# Is there any way to detect if a user agent is from a browser or an app?

Tags: python, http-headers, user-agent, mobile-application

I need to differentiate whether a User-Agent string from an HTTP header is from a mobile (iOS & Android) browser or a app. Is there any tool/library, preferably in Python which can help me with that?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/user-agents

Answer (score 7):

[user-agents](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/user-agents) is a fairly simple package for Python, which parses the `User-Agent` string.

```
from user_agents import parse

user_agent = parse(user_agent_string)
user_agent.os.family  # This will get you what you need
```

So having the OS family you can judge whether the request is made from a desktop browser or mobile browser or app client.

Comment: Just use user_agent.is_mobile and user_agent.is_pc.