# Prevent viewing my website on mobile device

Tags: javascript, python, html, web

Is there any way I can prevent my website from getting viewed or loaded on a mobile app using a Javascript?

This is because certain features of my web app do not display well on mobile. I may need to develop the mobile version later on.

And is there a javascript that can provide a message requesting a user to open the web app only on PC.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to determine if user is on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365352/easiest-way-to-determine-if-user-is-on-mobile-device)

Comment: You can use responsive design (viewport) and check if dimensions are less than usual monitor than you can drop alert or some message to use it on computer .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery). The accepted answer (1500+ up)  is plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

You can detect mobile device & document width and redirect to another page like this:

```
function detectmobile() {

    var a = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

if ( detectmobile() && document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 768 ){
    window.location.href = 'http://yourwebsite.com/pageformobiles';
}
```

But it's far better to detect the user-agent before the page (and all page resources, including javascript) is loaded and redirect users on your CMS level.

I haven't used Python that much to give you exact answer but please check the links below, they might be useful:

- [Is there any way to detect if a user agent is from a browser or an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30963473/is-there-any-way-to-detect-if-a-user-agent-is-from-a-browser-or-an-app)
- [Detect mobile devices with Django and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273319/detect-mobile-devices-with-django-and-python-3)
- [How do I check if a User is using a mobile device in Django 1.9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083195/how-do-i-check-if-a-user-is-using-a-mobile-device-in-django-1-9)
- [how to parse user agent string? python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209377/how-to-parse-user-agent-string-python)

Comment: It worked perfectly for my Django web app: adverto.ai. Until I develop the mobile app I want the user to use on laptop/desktop.